# Unmet dependencies when installing openjdk 7 on arm v7 running ubuntu

Tags: openjdk

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-7-jdk : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (>= 7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

sources

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise main universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise main universe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the solution by hit and trial. In `/etc/apt/sources.list` replaced `precise` with `trusty` and everything works. Now am able to install the `openjdk-7-jdk` package.

After changing it, `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like this.

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty main universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty main universe
```

Comment: you should be able to accept (mark) your own answer as the solution to close it out.